# unable to call API (WSO2)

Tags: wso2, wso2-micro-integrator

I'm using call mediator to call the Put API in WSO2, but I'm getting the following error.
The PUT API only accepts an authorization token in the header.

I'm using WSO2 integration studio and micro integrator.

WSO2 error:

```
[2023-02-22 12:43:15,177] ERROR {RelayUtils} - Error while building Passthrough stream org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character 'd' (code 100) after '<!' (malformed comment?)
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,3]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:570)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:566)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:165)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:169)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:122)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.util.PassThroughMessageHandler.buildMessage(PassThroughMessageHandler.java:103)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.buildMessage(AbstractListMediator.java:155)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:96)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:239)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.SwitchMediator.mediate(SwitchMediator.java:200)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.SwitchMediator.mediate(SwitchMediator.java:200)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:249)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:820)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:322)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:627)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:208)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:298)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character 'd' (code 100) after '<!' (malformed comment?)
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,3]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedChar(StreamScanner.java:639)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromPrologBang(BasicStreamReader.java:2422)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2063)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1134)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
    ... 23 more

[2023-02-22 12:43:15,177] ERROR {FilterMediator} - {api:PaymentAPI.xml} Error while building message. Error while building Passthrough stream org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while building Passthrough stream
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.handleException(RelayUtils.java:453)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:216)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:122)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.util.PassThroughMessageHandler.buildMessage(PassThroughMessageHandler.java:103)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.buildMessage(AbstractListMediator.java:155)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:96)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:239)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.SwitchMediator.mediate(SwitchMediator.java:200)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.SwitchMediator.mediate(SwitchMediator.java:200)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:249)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:820)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:322)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:627)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:208)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:298)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character 'd' (code 100) after '<!' (malformed comment?)
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,3]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:570)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:566)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:165)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:169)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character 'd' (code 100) after '<!' (malformed comment?)
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,3]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedChar(StreamScanner.java:639)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromPrologBang(BasicStreamReader.java:2422)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2063)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1134)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
    ... 23 more
```

source file:

```xml
<property description="Authorization" expression="fn:concat('Bearer ', get-property('access_token'))" name="Authorization" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
<call>
    <endpoint>
        <http method="put" uri-template="http://172.20.0.46:8181/company-registration-automation/api/v1/arkcase/case/?caseNumber={uri.var.caseid}&amp;caseStatus=Payment Pending">
            <suspendOnFailure>
                <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
            </suspendOnFailure>
            <markForSuspension>
                <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
            </markForSuspension>
        </http>
    </endpoint>
</call>
```

here the PUT API response Header:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjAAN.png)

i tried some axis2 properties but did't work.

can someone help me here :)

Comment: According to the above error, the issue happened when MI is trying to build the response from the PUT API. What's the content-type of that response?

Comment: there is no content-type in the response header
I have edit the the post above see image description

Comment: What is the response body you receive?

Comment: there is no response body only I have the response code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding the following property before the call mediator and after the call mediator?

```xml
<property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" value="true" scope="axis2" type="BOOLEAN"/>
```

Comment: I try this but got the same error

Comment: @ebadmahmood Please enable wirelogs by referring to this https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/develop/using-wire-logs/ and share the logs. Also, share the complete integration source up to the respond mediator.

Comment: I have to ask the developer to add content in response he added "success" with content-type : text/plain;charset=UTF-8

Comment: @ebadmahmood is the issue sorted now?

Comment: No, do i need to update MI/conf/axis2.xml ?

Comment: @ebadmahmood if you share the wirelogs I may be able to understand what's happening.